# How to add the input from InputBox into MsgBox

Tags: windows, vbscript, inputbox, msgbox

I want to add the inputted text from an MsgBox into a Msgbox I got this but it don't work. Can anyone help me?

```
Dim x
x = MsgBox("Welcome to this software. Are you new with this?", vbYesNo + 
vbQuestion, "Welcome!")
Dim f
f = strMessage =Inputbox("First enter your name","The software")
Dim z
z = MsgBox(Welcome strMessage!)
```

Comment: `z = MsgBox("Welcome " & strMessage & "!")`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with what you have here. I'll go through them one by one.

```
f = strMessage = InputBox("First enter your name","The software")
```

I assume you're trying to store the value the user entered into the `InputBox` into some variable--either `f`, or `strMessage`, or maybe both. VBScript does not allow multiple assignments in the way that you've written them. Instead, VBScript is testing whether the value stored in `strMessage` (which you haven't declared or initialized) is equal to the value the user entered. The value of that test (which will be either True or False) is then stored in `f`.

If you're trying to store the user's input in just `f`, this will work:

```
f = InputBox("First enter your name","The software")
```

If you want to store it in both `f` and `strMessage`, you'll need two assignment statements:

```
Dim strMessage
f = InputBox("First enter your name","The software")
strMessage = f
```

Next, there are a couple issues with these lines:

```
Dim z
z = MsgBox(Welcome strMessage!)
```

First, `MsgBox` with only one argument will always return 1, so there's no real use in having variable `z`.

Next, you haven't put quotes around the first argument to `MsgBox`. As a result, `Welcome strMessage!` confuses the interpreter, and throws an error. If you instead add quotes, `"Welcome strMessage!"`, that will resolve the error.

I expect, however, you want to display the user's input back to them. In that case, you can't just put the variable within the quotes--you need to concatenate it on, using `&`. Thus, you should come to:

```
MsgBox("Welcome, " & f & "!")
```

Finally, an important note, the variable names you have (`x`, `f`, `strMessage`, and `z`) not particularly descriptive. Consider some helpful names, like `isUserNew` and `userName`. With those changes, you'd get to:

```
Dim isUserNew
Dim userName

isUserNew = MsgBox("Welcome to this software. Are you new with this?", vbYesNo, "Welcome!")
userName = Inputbox("First enter your name","The software")
MsgBox("Welcome, " & userName & "!")
```